# Office 365 Sharepoint API $skip/$skiptoken functionality

Tags: odata, office365

Going through the documentation for the Sharepoint API (located here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605900(v=office.15).aspx) I am trying to figure out how to select chunks of documents. I was expecting $skip to work, as it is implied that most OData functionality should be present, but this doesn't work. I also can't figure out whether or not $skiptoken is a valid query param. It's listed in the documentation near the bottom (without further explanation), but I can't coax the proper result out of it so far.

If somebody knows about $skip or $skiptoken or another method available for getting chunked responses back, help with this problem would be great!

EDIT: to clarify, things like API_URL/files?$orderby=url&$top=5 work, but things like API_URL/files?$orderby=url&$skip=50 do not. However, I have just found a 'next' URL in the response which appears to provide server-side paging support. I'll try to figure out the use of $skiptoken from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OData V4 protocol has specified (referencing [11.2.5.7 Server-Driven Paging](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793701)) that:

> OData services may use the reserved system query option $skiptoken when building next links. Its content is opaque, **service-specific**, and must only follow the rules for URL query parts.
>   OData clients **MUST NOT** use the system query option $skiptoken when constructing requests.

Thus, the implementation of the O365 SharePoint API that it publishes $skiptoken as a query option that the client should use for excluding first few items in the queried collection is a violation of the protocol. The client should use $skip for such scenario. But it seems from the O365 spec you attached that $skip is not implemented.

If you query a entity set of the O365 service and the response payload contains a next link (a `@odata.nextLink` annotation in the response JSON object), then it indicates that the service has server-side paging for the entity set. Typically the next link would be a URL containing the $skiptoken query option such as `http://host/service/entityset?$skiptoken=n` that the client can use for getting the next page.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it looks like in addition to $skip, there is no implementation for $search and $filter.

Comment: Currently, the service only supports forward paging by use of the $skiptoken and the nextlink. It is a known that the $skip functionality isn't available yet in the service. The development team is aware of this ask.

Comment: @MichaelMainer-Microsoft, this functionality never made it over to 2013. What is the recommended way to implement paging? Use _vti_bin/ListData.svc?

Comment: Well, it turns out $filter is implemented, unlike I stated above, but a lot of the functions to be used with it are not, and are available for use only on certain columns. It's too bad, however, that I have to do so much deep documentation digging and experimentation to figure this out, rather than having a single, clear document that lays out what is available

Comment: @John Palmer, I'm only now learning about SharePoint APIs for O365. I'm not sure about APIs for 2013.

Comment: @MichaelMainer-Microsoft For REST OData APIs, they are (or rather should be) identical.  Both SharePoint on-premises and Online have shorted functionality that exists in the 2010 API.